# How to disable mail modification in iOS Gmail app

Tags: ios, css, mobile, gmail, media-queries

The question is: is a possible to disable gmail app on iOS modification to screen fit. Any `media-queries` or style changes not working. This feature is crashing my mails and i need to fix this somehow. Can any body help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, i found some solution. What i need was this:

```
/* 
 DO NOT REMOVE - mobile autofit converter disable - DO NOT REMOVE
*/

<div style="display: none; white-space: nowrap; font: 15px courier; color: #333333;">
    - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
</div>
```

Put this at the bottom off your mail code, but jus before `table` tag close. If your email have more that standard `600px` width add another `- -` to fit it correctly. Also as a `color` set color of your email background. That's it.